# open form on html button click in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

will any body help me in opening a form on button click?? Thanks in advance.

**aspx.cs Code:**

```
        public string wogrid()
        {
            string htmlStr = "";
            con.COpen();
            string qry = "SELECT id,casetype,Case when status_c=1 then 'Active' else 'Inactive' End as status_c FROM t_claimtype";
            SqlDataReader rd = gd.DataReader(qry);
            while (rd.Read())
            {
                int ID = Convert.ToInt16(rd["id"].ToString());
                string caseType = rd["casetype"].ToString();
                string status = rd["status_c"].ToString(); 
                htmlStr += "<tr><td>" + ID + "</td>" + "<td>" + caseType + "</td>" + "<td>" + status + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<input type='submit' id='" + (rd)["ID"].ToString() + "' name='edit' value='EDIT' **onclick='windows.open(viewClaims.aspx)'** runat='server' />" + "</td></tr>";

            }
            con.cClose();
            return htmlStr;
        }
private void AddPlanToCart()
        {
            Response.Redirect("viewClaims.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  What specifically do you mean by "open a form"?  Are you just trying to direct the user to a page when they click on a button?  Why not use a link, since that's exactly what a link is for?  If you want it to be a button, where is your button click event handler?  What isn't working in that?  What does the code shown have to do with the question?  At the moment it sounds like you're just looking for some introductory help in ASP.NET and how to make a link or a button, which is generally covered by tutorials.  Can you clarify?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to redirect to other page. and i had added the button code in <td> tag and that's the main problem I'm unable to introduce the handler!

Comment: You should really just use a link for this instead of a button.  There's no need to involve ASP.NET server-side code at all.  A simple HTML `<a href="...">` is fine.  But if you *insist* on using a button, you are encouraged to start with some introductory tutorials on ASP.NET to learn how to create and use button elements.  Any introductory tutorial will get you started on that.  Generally in Visual Studio once you place a button on the design surface you can double-click on it to create a click handler.

Comment: returning server side like `... runat='server' />` directly to the client would not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This results in invalid JavaScript:

```
onclick='windows.open(viewClaims.aspx)'
```

Because:

- There is no `windows` object, it's called `window`.
- You didn't enclose the string `"viewClaims.aspx"` in quotes.

Additionally, HTML attributes should be enclosed in double-quotes.  JavaScript strings can be single-quoted or double-quoted, so you have flexibility there.  In order to do this on your current line of code you will need to "escape" some of the quotes.  (This should be expected any time you try to mix *three different languages* on *one line of code*.)

Also additionally, this `<input/>` element should not include `runat="server"` because it's not a server-side control.  That attribute wouldn't mean anything to a web browser and would just be ignored.

(Also remove those `*` characters.  I'm sure they were there in an attempt to highlight that part of the code here in your post, but effectively they are invalid code and should be removed.)

Putting this together, this string literal that you currently have:

```
"' name='edit' value='EDIT' **onclick='windows.open(viewClaims.aspx)'** runat='server' />"
```

would become this:

```
"' name=\"edit\" value=\"EDIT\" onclick=\"windows.open('viewClaims.aspx')\" />"
```

---

Semantically your really shouldn't be using a button at all for this in the first place.  The functionality you're building is to direct the user to another page when they click on something.  A *link* already does that.  And it does it by default without the need for JavaScript or trying to get around the use of a form or any other hacks.

Just use a link:

```
"<a href=\"viewClaims.aspx\" id=\"" + (rd)["ID"].ToString() + "\">Edit</a>"
```